# Ayuda.. Iniciar animacion de Contador al hacer scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Me encontre este ejemplo de contador y mi duda es como hacer que ese ejemplo de contador inicie al hacer scroll

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4z0wbLoh/3/)

```js
$.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function( options ) {
      var settings = $.extend({
          start:  0,
          end:    100,
          easing: 'swing',
          duration: 400,
          complete: ''
      }, options );

      var thisElement = $(this);

      $({count: settings.start}).animate({count: settings.end}, {
      duration: settings.duration,
      easing: settings.easing,
      step: function() {
        var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
        thisElement.text(mathCount);
      },
      complete: settings.complete
    });
  };


$('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 450,duration: 3000});
$('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 20,duration: 3000});
$('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 700,duration: 2000});
$('#number4').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 8,duration: 2500});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes usar es el evento de `JQuery` llamado `scroll()`, para detectar el `scroll` de tu ventana, y pues solo necesitas después comparar la posición de tu `scroll` con la posición de tu `div` principal del contador y ejecutarlo:

```js
$.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function( options ) {
      var settings = $.extend({
          start:  0,
          end:    100,
          easing: 'swing',
          duration: 400,
          complete: ''
      }, options );

      var thisElement = $(this);

      $({count: settings.start}).animate({count: settings.end}, {
      duration: settings.duration,
      easing: settings.easing,
      step: function() {
        var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
        thisElement.text(mathCount);
      },
      complete: settings.complete
    });
  };
  var seEjecuto = 0;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $("#projectFacts").position().top && seEjecuto === 0) {
  seEjecuto = 1;
  $('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({start: 0,end: 450,duration: 3000});
  $('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({start: 0,end: 20,duration: 3000});
  $('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({start: 0,end: 700,duration: 2000});
  $('#number4').jQuerySimpleCounter({start: 0,end: 8,duration: 2500});
}
});
```

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: table;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#projectFacts .fullwidth{
  padding: 0;
}
.factswrap{
    display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.factswrap .item{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  transition:  all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.factswrap .item:nth-child(1){
  background: #004b87;
}
.factswrap .item:nth-child(2){
  background: #175b91;
}
.factswrap .item:nth-child(3){
  background: #004b87;
}
.factswrap .item:nth-child(4){
  background: #175b91;
}
.factswrap .item p.number{
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.factswrap .item p{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: bold;
  transition:  all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.factswrap .item span.Line-under{
  width: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition:  all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.factswrap .item img{
    width: 80px;
    opacity: .8;
    transition:  all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.factswrap .item:hover img, .factswrap .item:hover p{
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.factswrap .item:hover span{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
<div id="projectFacts" class="sectionClass">
  <div class="fullwidth height columns">
    <div class="factswrap" onscroll="myFunction()">
      <div class="item fadeupbig animated animated" data-number="450" style="visibility: visible;">
        <img src="img/networking.png" alt="">
        <p id="number1" class="number">0</p>
        <span class="Line-under"></span>
        <p>Lorem</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item fadeupbig animated animated" data-number="20" style="visibility: visible;">
        <img src="img/portfolio.png" alt="">
        <p id="number2" class="number">0</p>
        <span class="Line-under"></span>
        <p>Lorem</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item fadeupbig animated animated" data-number="700" style="visibility: visible;">
        <img src="img/handshake.png" alt="">
        <p id="number3" class="number">0</p>
        <span class="Line-under"></span>
        <p>Lorem</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item fadeupbig animated animated" data-number="8" style="visibility: visible;">
        <img src="img/company.png" alt="">
        <p id="number4" class="number">0</p>
        <span class="Line-under"></span>
        <p>Lorem</p>
      </div>                  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
```

Nota: La variable `seEjecuto`, la uso para validar que el contador solo se ejecute una vez.